# Looping OGG files with Adobe Alchemy

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, oggvorbis

I'm trying to use Adobe's OggVorbis library. But I can't seem to get the Sound object to loop.
I even tried looping the _sound object inside the AudioDecoder.as in the "com.automatastudios.audio.audiodecoder" package.

Do you really have to reload the file and stream it over and over?

Comment: You can use this very simple frontend which supports loops:
http://mauft.com/2010/11/ogg-vorbis-in-flash/

Answer (score 0):

If you're streaming, then yes you'll have to jump back the beginning of the stream.  A stream, by definition, is a constant link to the server and does minimal loading of files locally.

But, if you're not really streaming, you should have no problem loading up a file and caching it locally then playing it over and over.

Since you mention Alchemy, there may be other unknown issues if you're trying to use a converted C library, as opposed to native ActionScript.

[Note; I didn't know the OggVorbis library for Flex before now].